# Property 'api' does not exist on type 'AgGridReact'

Tags: typescript, ag-grid

I'm trying to use `ag-grid` in a `react` `tyescript` project and I am facing problems with types when doing the tutorial. At the [Enable Selection](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/getting-started/#enable-selection-2) part.

In line: `const selectedNodes: RowNode[] = gridRef.current.api.getSelectedNodes();`

Error: `Property 'api' does not exist on type 'AgGridReact'`

Even when defining: `const gridRef = useRef<AgGridReact>(null);`

I took a look at `agGridReat.d.ts`:

```
export declare class AgGridReact extends Component<AgGridReactProps | AgReactUiProps, {}> {
    api: GridApi;
    columnApi: ColumnApi;
    private setGridApi;
    render(): JSX.Element;
}
```

Seems like `api` is defined here.
Is there a way to avoid all these problems but still using typescript? What am I missing?

Comment: Make sure you have the import
`import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react/lib/agGridReact';` (not `import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';` )

Comment: @ccheneson seems like that's what I needed. But why and also how did you know?

Comment: I copied/pasted your snippets and I observe the same thing as you did. I remembered I had 2 choices from vscode et I tried the other one. I think your snippet with the definition of the class and the correct import file are the same. I dunno when you would use the other import.

Comment: Not sure if you get the same result, but it looks like `const selectedNodes: RowNode[] | undefined = (gridRef.current as AgGridReact).props.api?.getSelectedNodes();` works with the `import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';`